# What is an uncategorized URL

Tags: seo, url, links

What is an uncategorized URL and is this something to worry about for a standard niche website?

Comment: Where did you read that term?

Comment: Somewhere in these forums someone said that an uncategorized URL was not good for SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An uncategorized URL is an URL without any category, logical right?

For example, in a blog (about webmastering), you can categorize articles (thus URL) into categories (HTML, CSS, SEO, etc.) and get URLs like this:

- `www.example.com/html/my-first-article/`
- `www.example.com/css/my-second-article/`
- `www.example.com/seo/my-third-article/`
- etc.

However, you can have some pages you don't want to classify because it's not relevant; for example the contact page. In this case, the contact page is uncategorized and you have this URL: `www.example.com/contact/` (no special category). It's totally normal and in general, uncategorized pages are not harmful at all for SEO. They are very strong pages for a website because in general, they get a backlink from all pages of the website.

Comment: Ok thank you for responding. So it would not benefit my site to go through all my pages and create categories? At the moment all the pages (200+) on my website are of this format: www.website.com/natural-health.html

Comment: Depending of architecture you want for your site. If all your pages can be classified into categories, it's most probably a good idea to categorize them because it's easier for a user to navigate through categories than a website with no architecture.

Comment: I have the home page, tier 2 pages and tier 3 pages. All the tier 3s point to tier 2s, and the breadcrumbs show the hierarchy. To change the categories for the whole site would be a lot of work, and would probably involve losing all the keyword rank positions and having to redirect each old page to each new page. Will it be worth the effort for google rankings/ visitor numbers?

Comment: OK, just ask you one question. Is it easy for users to navigate through the site? If yes, don't change the architecture. If it can be improved significantly, you can change the architecture.

Comment: I don't see how the URL itself would help user navigation, as long as the top nav and links from articles to other articles are clear.

Comment: It's just more intuitive when the URL respect the architecture of the site. Otherwise, the user can be confused. Indeed, when a page is uncategorized, by looking the URL, you don't know where you are in the site. For example, you can't change easily the URL to go back to the category.

Comment: I just want to add that there is a lot of SEO hooey out there by all the *me too* bloggers who are trying to carve out a space in the SEO game for themselves. Most of what you will read is just plain *bull(!)* and should be ignored. Just make sites for people and follow the common sense SEO stuff. There are no magic buttons, no special sequence of incantations and rituals, you do not have to shave your head and wear a pony-tail and shake a tambourine, it is not a MLM, no selling Tupperware, no snakes to handle and Bible verses to read, and no special fees involved for secrets.

Comment: I'd be interested in some examples of the SEO hooey out there... so as not to fall for it. Or 'safe' sources of good information to follow. (I like your 'follow the money' logic)